# How many times has a cricket player got ten wickets and a fifty in a test match?

Tags: cricket, statistics

After seeing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqri1-ofMP4) I wondered: how many times has a bowler scored fifty runs and also had a ten-wicket haul in the same test match?

Comment: I presume you mean fifty runs in a single innings, rather than fifty runs in the match - you may wish to edit your question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 19 October 2016, there have been [25 instances of a player taking 10 wickets in a match and scoring fifty or more runs in an innings](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=start;qualmin2=10;qualmin3=1;qualval2=wickets;qualval3=fifty_plus;template=results;type=allround;view=match). Sir Richard Hadlee is currently the only player to have done so more than once: he achieved the feat in three Tests.

Comment: Nice one - I spent a couple of hours playing with the Statsguru interface but couldn't figure out how to make it accept the two restrictions for the same match, not separate ones. How did you manage that?

Comment: @TrueDub Under "Advanced filter", enter a condition under "Result qualifications". Pressing "Add to query" will then log the condition and return you to the same page, allowing you to go through the process again to add another condition. Repeat as desired!

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was doing 2 things wrong - I used the "10 wickets in a match" filter, which was incorrect, and I failed to use Match Total as the ordering factor. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

At least four other players have achieved and surpassed this, by scoring  100 runs and taking 10 wickets in a match. Of course to score 100 runs in a match, you need to score at least one half-century.

1. Alan Davidson for Australia (scores 44 and 80)
2. Ian Botham for England (score 114, batted once)
3. Imran Khan for Pakistan (score 117, batted once)
4. Shakib al Hasan for Bangladesh (scores 137 and 6)

http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/287370.html

So the number of players achieving the feat of scoring a half-century in one innings and taking 10 wickets in a match will probably be considerably larger than these four and Steyn (mentioned in question).